# Sorting List ascending and descending android java

Tags: java, android

I have a `List<>` containing data. How can I sort it to ascending and descending?

```
List<Data> data = new ArrayList<>();

        data.add(new Data("Batman vs Superman", "Following the destruction of Metropolis, Batman embarks on a personal vendetta against Superman ", R.drawable.ic_action_movie));
        data.add(new Data("X-Men: Apocalypse", "X-Men: Apocalypse is an upcoming American superhero film based on the X-Men characters that appear in Marvel Comics ", R.drawable.ic_action_movie));
        data.add(new Data("Captain America: Civil War", "A feud between Captain America and Iron Man leaves the Avengers in turmoil.  ", R.drawable.ic_action_movie));
        data.add(new Data("Kung Fu Panda 3", "After reuniting with his long-lost father, Po  must train a village of pandas", R.drawable.ic_action_movie));
        data.add(new Data("Warcraft", "Fleeing their dying home to colonize another, fearsome orc warriors invade the peaceful realm of Azeroth. ", R.drawable.ic_action_movie));
        data.add(new Data("Alice in Wonderland", "Alice in Wonderland: Through the Looking Glass ", R.drawable.ic_action_movie));
```

this is my data class

```
public class Data {
    public String title;
    public String description;
    public int imageId;

    Data(String title, String description, int imageId) {
        this.title = title;
        this.description = description;
        this.imageId = imageId;
    }

}
```

Comment: This can be done using a comparator. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html

Comment: By calling [`data.sort(comparator)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#sort-java.util.Comparator-) (Java 8) or [`Collections.sort(data, comparator)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-java.util.Comparator-) (any Java), where `comparator` is a [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) to apply the ordering you want.

Comment: i have beginner making movies news apps could you please try to help me a bit of code :)

Comment: Collections.sort(data, new Comparator<List>()
        {
            public int compare(List o1, List o2)
            {
                return o1.compareTo(o2);
            }
        });  did not work

Comment: Side note: `data` is not a great variable name, and it's an even worse class name, as it describes nothing about its contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let your class implement the `Comparable` interface, this lets Java handle most of the heavy lifting.

```
public class Data implements Comparable<Data>{
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Data another) {
        return this.title.compareTo(another.title);
        // can also compareToIgnoreCase if not case sensitive
    }
}
```

Then simply call `Collections.sort(data);`

This will sort your data based on the `compareTo` function in your Data class.

Comment: work as expected but only working as ascending what about descending

Comment: For descending you can use the .reverse() call after you call.sort()

Comment: @AndroidGuy007 you can either do what slambeth said, or you can use `return another.title.compareTo(this.title);` I believe.

Answer (score -1):

You can do using Java8 as below:

**data.sort((Data d1, Data d2) -> d1.title.compareTo(d2.title));**

In your code, I recommend NOT to expose the class fields directly with 'public', rather use getters and setters (encapsulate the fields).

**data.sort((Data d1, Data d2) -> d1.getTitle().compareTo(d2.getTitle()));**

Comment: If you have Java 8, why wouldn't you use `comparing(Data::getTitle)`?

Comment: The reason, I did NOT use it because the current Data class NOT having the getters and setters, so I have given both options with and without getters and setters.

Comment: Then why wouldn't you use `comparing((Data d) -> d.title)`?